# get total of column in datagridview

Tags: string, vb.net, types, datagridview, double

i have get data in to data grid view column

dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim

now i need to get sum of the column "DEBIT" , for this ...

```
        Dim tot As Integer = 0

             For i As Integer = 0 To dgvAccDetail.RowCount - 1
            tot += dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value

        Next
        If tot = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Records Found")
        End If

        TXTVoucherDTotal.Text = tot.ToString()
```

but i got msg

"conversion from string to type double is not valid"

plz tell me what is wrong with this code ,

Comment: What is your data source? Is it a datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set Option strict on, it will help you avoid many errors in future.  With option strict off, the compiler must infer data types and that's why your calculation won't work.

Secondly, change this line:

```
dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim 
'This line doesn't compile with option strict on
```

To

```
dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Cells("DEBIT").Value()
```

Lastly, you are trying to do mathematical operations with text, you need to convert the cell value to the correct format first.

```
If dgvAccDetail.rows.count > 0

     Dim tot As double = 0 'integer will only work for whole numbers.
                           'It will disregard fractional values if set to integer.

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvAccDetail.Rows.Count - 1
            tot = tot + Cdbl(dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

        Next

    TXTVoucherDTotal.Text = Format(tot,"0.00")

Else

    MessageBox.Show("No Records Found")

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to add a string value to an integer value.
`dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value` returns a string.
You can parse it to an integer:

```
tot += Integer.Parse(dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
```

Comment: thanx for reply,  now i got other msg  "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: What is the string's value?

Comment: it 600  --- dgvAccDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dtVD.Rows(i).Item("DEBIT").ToString.Trim

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 For i = 0 To dgvAccDetail.RowCount - 1
        tot += Cint(dgvAccDetail(4, i).Value)
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The compute method of a DataTable takes 2 strings; an expression and a filter. Use the appropriate column in the DataTable.

```
 Dim columnSum As Integer = CInt(dtVD.Compute("Sum(DEBIT)", Nothing))
```